# why would my bash function complete wildcards for variables?

Tags: bash, function, alias

In my ~/.bash_aliases:

```
function wtf (){
  echo $1;
}
```

Testing in bash:

```
>>  wtf t*
testes
```

WTF?

---

Now that I understand that bash is parsing my wildcard before passing it on, I thought I would share the function that I was building. Here's the final version of my recursive delete shortcut:

```
# delete recursively
function rmr () {
    find . -name "$1" -type f -delete -exec \
    echo $(tput setaf 1)"deleted >"$(tput setaf 2) {} \; ;
    l;
}
```

Comment: Replace `t*` by `"t*"` to prevent bash from globbing.

Comment: @Cyrus That only defers globbing. When `$1` (unquoted) is expanded, its value is subject to pathname expansion as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you have a file called `testes`, and bash replaces `t*` with that **before** passing arguments to `wtf()`. You may have several files starting with `t`, but `testes` is the first, and `wtf` only echoes `$1`. If you replace `$1` with `$*` you will see all of them.

E.g., if you have files `testes` and `tumble` (and no other file starting with `t`), and issue

```
wtf t*
```

bash will replace `t*` with `testes tumble` (space-separated) and then evaluate the line

```
wtf testes tumble
```

which will cause `wtf` to be passed `testes` as `$1` and `tumble` as `$2`.

If you don't want the shell to do filename expansion, you have to put quotes around your argument, like `wtf 't*'` or `wtf "t*"`. Single quotes have the advantage of not only avoiding filename expansion, put also any other kind of expansion (e.g. parameter expansion and variable expansion). Filename (or pathname) expansion happens with `*`, `?` (among others), parameter and variable expansion with `$`.

For the same reason, you must quote the argument of `echo`, this time in double quotes, because you want parameter expansion of `$1` to happen, but don't want (again!) filename expansion to happen:

```
function wtf() {
  echo "$1"
}
```

`man bash` is your friend, there is a lot to learn.

Within `man bash`, type `/^EXPANSION` or `/Pathname Expansion`. See also `/^QUOTING`.

Comment: This is not complete. Quoting `t*` indeed prevents the shell from expanding the pattern before passing it to the function, but leaving `$1` unquoted will allow the shell to expand it after the parameter itself is expanded.

Comment: excellent description of all the stuff i didn't know. it makes perfect sense now; i was obviously stuck with the understanding the bash is just pushing my stuff to the function which then does what it needs to do.

Answer (score 4):

That's just how shells work. It's not your function doing the expansion, it is the shell that does it before calling your function.

You'll need to quote anything you want preserved (including globbing characters `*` and `?`) when calling the function *and* inside the function.

```
wtf() {
  echo "$1"
}

wtf 't*'
```